# Unable to mount file on windows from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I made a file on Azure using "File Service" and then tried to mount it using "connect". It has given me the username: localhost\xyz.
Two questions:

1. why username starting from "localhost" and not with "Azure"?
2. why I am unable to mount as windows security not giving any error, instead keep on turning back to credentials page?

p.s. TCP port 445 working properly..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few workarounds that worked for us.

**WAY-1**

You can directly go to your PowerShell of your machine and paste the script that you have provided in your storage account
[image]
[image]

---

**WAY-2**

You can click on More options and select for different account and then use the ***storage account name*** prepended with `AZURE\` as the username and a ***storage account key*** as the password.

[image: A screenshot of the network credential dialog]

---

**WAY-3**

You can create a file share directly by unchecking the `connect using different credentials`.

[image]

**OUTPUT:**

For all the above ways here is the screenshot of fileshares that got mounted.
[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Mount SMB Azure file share on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#mount-the-azure-file-share)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried way 1, it gives me this error:         WARNING: TCP connect to (**.23*.1*0.** : 445) failed
WARNING: Ping to **.23*.1*0.** failed with status: TimedOut                                                                                        --- Also, TCP port 445 is listening                                                                                                              ---Way 2 and 3 I tried already and its not working

Comment: If anything is mounted, Can you unmount and then try again

Comment: None is mounted. I got this in diagnose panel: Azure Cosmos DB - East US
Active: An emerging issue is under investigation.
Starting at 12:30 UTC on 04 Jan 2022, Customers using Azure Cosmos DB in East US may experience issues accessing services. New connections to databases in this subscription in this region may result in an error or timeout. Existing connections remain available to accept new requests, however if those connections are terminated then re-establishing them may fail.